# Request Line is too large - Gunicorn

Tags: python, rest, flask, backend, gunicorn

I have been using Flask for over a year, I used deploy my Flask app into production using Gunicorn WSGI server. Recently I encountered a weird error that,

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Bad Request</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1><p>Bad Request</p></h1>
    Request Line is too large (4269 &gt; 4094)
  </body>
</html>
```

I encountered this error for most of my `GET` requests.

While debugging I came to know that, I need to increase the `--limit-request-line` config in Gunicorn after I increased that to `8190` in my `Dockerfile`, I was able to see the responses from the Flask app successfully.

The dockerfile change I made was

```
CMD gunicorn app:app  -w 2 --threads 50 -b 0.0.0.0:8080 --limit-request-line 8190 --capture-output --log-level info
```

My question here is,
Why did the `http request line size/length` increase suddenly, because I haven't redeployed my Flask app in past 40 days, so the `Gunicorn` version wasn't changed. The server was returning responses perfectly for 39 days, then suddenly it gave me this error.

Any idea on this?

Edit1:
I found that the issue was due to the large get request being formed due to multiple filter values.

Comment: The size of the requests you receive must have increased... What requests are you getting that are that long?

Comment: Most of my GET APIs, but these requests were working fine, I didn't make any change to them

Answer (score 0):

Set `--limit-request-line` to 0. This will allow unlimited request length. However, add a request size validation inside code to avoid any security risks.